# How can we add oauth2( serviceaccount) with emailsettings?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-email-settings-api

Previously we are using https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0 following approach to manage SendAs GET and SET.

```
        gmailFilterService = new GmailFilterService(this.applicationName);
        gmailFilterService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);
        gmailFilterService.setReadTimeout(Lxxx.readTimeout);
        gmailFilterService.useSsl();
```

How can we use this with oauth2 with service account

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
         .setTransport(httpTransport)
         .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
         .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
         .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER , DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT))
         .setServiceAccountUser(adminEmail)
         .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
             new java.io.File(serviceAccountPKCS12FilePath))
         .build();
```

Comment: Check these links for https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client and https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/ for oauth2.0 service account

Answer (score 0):

```
gmailFilterService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

Added jar files:

- core-1.47.1.jar (new)
- guava.jar (new)

removed jar files:

- gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar (dead)
- gdata-base-1.0.jar (dead)
- gdata-client-1.0.jar (dead)
- gdata-core-1.0.jar (dead)
- google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar (dead)
- google-oauth-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar (dead)
- google-oauth-client-java6-1.20.0.jar (dead)
- google-oauth-client-jetty-1.20.0.jar (dead)
- google-oauth-client-servlet-1.20.0.jar (dead)